# Authorization header not reaching the server in laravel project

Tags: laravel, header, jwt, token, hosting

I'm using JWT token to authorize android users but when i send it it reaches as null, does the server remove the Authorization header? is there a config i need to change to allow my header to pass to the backend?

Comment: how do you send the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow the second solution.**

I faced this issue in cPanel hosting, some security mod or plugins strips the Authorization data from the header, I was using `Authorization Bearer`. I bypassed it by renaming `Authorization` -> `ApiToken` and updating few lines of code in Laravel core.

file `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput.php` method `bearerToken`.

```
public function bearerToken()
{
    $header = $this->header('Authorization', $this->header('ApiToken', ''));

    if (Str::startsWith($header, 'Bearer ')) {
        return Str::substr($header, 7);
    }
}
```

Btw, editing core code is not ideal.

Answer (score 20):

Just updating for the Googlers as I was also looking for a solution and felt that modifying the core code isn't a good idea!

The solution I've got is to use middleware. In my JavaScript, I'm setting `X-Authorization` headers instead of `Authorization`.

I've then created an HTTP middleware class to pick up this header and set our Authorization header -

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class XAuthorizationHeader
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        // check if we have an X-Authorization header present
        if($auth = $request->header('X-Authorization')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', $auth);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in `App\Http\Kernel.php` `$middleware` array, add this middleware at the very start.

`protected $middleware = [
        XAuthorizationHeader::class,`

Any further code will then be able to retrieve the `Authorization` header as if it were actually there when you pass it as an `X-Authorization` header.

Comment: @theinquisitor This should be the accepted answer, editing framework should not be the answer in any case.

Comment: Any way of changing the accepted answer other than user marking it? I agree people googling for this solution shouldn't be presented with one about modifying the core code!

Comment: No idea, I just flag the answer to pay attention any moderator.

Comment: still facting the same issue on laravel 8

Answer (score 13):

Add Authorization handling code in public/.htaccess:

`# Handle Authorization Header
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

Ref: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: I have updated in root .htaccess work perfectly due to ssl installed

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me as well. For anyone working only with a vhost file, you can add this to it.
 # Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar kind of issue. Actually, we need to enable the rewrite rules in two places.

Add Authorization handling code in public/.htaccess:

## Handle Authorization Header

**RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]**

Add the same code in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled**
**# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]**